# Create Array of values from Array of objects with value as a property

Tags: java, collections

i wish to get the value of name from : [sailpoint.object.Identity@4099209b[id=8a029c656b800bf9016b801a2d130014,name=100] which is stored in a list.Please assist.

**Code Snippet:**

```
// getObjects reurn identity objects e.g. sailpoint.object.Identity@43ac0a68[id=8a029c656b800bf9016b801a2eae0017,name=101]

List<Identity> identities = context.getObjects(Identity.class, query);
```

**Results now:**

```
[sailpoint.object.Identity@4099209b[id=8a029c656b800bf9016b801a2d130014,name=100], sailpoint.object.Identity@43ac0a68[id=8a029c656b800bf9016b801a2eae0017,name=101]]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[100,101]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a definition of the `Identity` object I can only assume that the `name` property is local (and exposed via `Identity#getName()`. In that case, you can simply [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) ("translate") each collection item:

```
List<String> names = context.getObjects(Identity.class, query).stream()
  .map(Identity::getName)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd stream the list and use a getter to extract the name:

```
List<String> result = 
    identities.stream().map(Identity::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Oh, beat me to it :-S